# How to check if product has attribute in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

Simple question but I don't know what is wrong. I want to check if product has attributes or combinations. If i write:

```
{$product->id_product_attribute|@print_r}
```

I have no results. What is wrong ?

Comment: what version of PS are you using?

Comment: 1.6.1.13 Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a product has attributes with the following:

`$product->hasAttributes()` is used in php files

and

`$product.id_product_attribute == 0 or >0` is used in tpl files.

A great resource for finding things of this nature is to look through Prestashop's Github repo for 1.6 E.G. in this instance, the [Product.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Product.php#L2223) class.